# How To Specify Numbering To Specific Pages Only

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, overleaf, setcounter

I tried `\setcounter{page}{1}` but its giving me extra page after a section i dont why

Code -

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
 
\usepackage{geometry}

% Set the page margins
\geometry{
    paperwidth=8in,
    paperheight=11in,
    left=0.75in,
    right=0.75in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    headheight=0in,
    headsep=0in,
    footskip=0in,
    includeheadfoot,
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \null\vfill % Add vertical space and center the following content
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
   Title Page
  \end{center}
  \vfill 
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{1},

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\begin{titlepage}
  \null\vfill % Add vertical space and center the following content
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
   Title Page
  \end{center}
  \vfill 
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

I dont want to number title page and the number should be in continuation after second title page too and the empty page coming how to remove it